# Windows not recognizing CD/DVD drive

Tags: windows-7, windows, optical-drive, disk-management

I have an Acer Aspire laptop running Windows 7.

It has (suddenly) stopped recognizing any CD/DVD that I put in the drive.

When I insert a disk, it seems to be processing it for a couple of seconds but then just stops and nothing happens.

When I open Windows Explorer, it doesn't show up on the lefthand navigation bar. However, when I click on "Computer", it does show up in the righthand details.

When I click on it from there, it tries to read it and then pops up a dialog box: "Insert a Disc. Please insert a disc into drive F:." and pops out the drive's drawer.

I've tried all 5 "resolutions" on [this list from MS](http://support2.microsoft.com/?scid=kb;en-us;314060&x=12&y=13) and none have helped

Any suggestions? I can't seem to figure out how to fix this.

Comment: I would try replacing the drive.  When I had a similar problem a few years ago, the only thing that worked, was a new drive.  This is unlikely a software issue if the device is seen in device manager.

Comment: Completing all of those steps means software is not the issue. Hardware is. Try to get a new drive through the manufacture or through third party (Amazon may have it). Otherwise, if it's feasible for you, you can buy a USB CD/DVD Drive and plug it in for use.

Comment: Agree with ^ Reeves the symptoms from what you related so far is the hardware is not reading the disk. Have you tried a non-burned CD, a glass mastered store bought CD instead of a dye change cd to see if it works?  As an optical drive unit ages, the laser diode gets weak (from use), general airborn pollutions diffuse the light some (from just existing), and it becomes the end of its life. Glass masted optical disks have much stonger contrast, and do not have the problems of a poorly burned dye change cd. Testing a store bought CD would be important to knowing if it is poorly burned CDs or not

Answer (score 2):

The best solution is to change the drive. At some point, I had to do it in my every laptop.
You could try some magic, cleaning stuff for optical drives as a last resort.

Acer don't have a good opinion when it comes to hardware durability.